# Rearranging bits in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let's say I have `A = 0b11110101`.

I want to make a new integer like this pseudocode

```
B[0] = A[4]
B[1] = A[7]
B[2] = A[0]
B[3] = A[6]
B[4] = A[1]
B[5] = A[2]
B[6] = A[3]
B[7] = A[5]
```

How can I do that?

Maybe I can create an array B first, but at the end I need an integer/binary.

**Update #1**

I made something like this:

```
num=0
pc1_tidyHex = []

pc1_tidyHex.append([tidyHex[56], tidyHex[48], tidyHex[40], tidyHex[32], tidyHex[24], tidyHex[16], tidyHex[8]])
num = int(''.join(map(str, pc1_tidyHex)))    
print(pc1_tidyHex)
print(num)
```

and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\TUC Aux\python\budi.py", line 47, in <module>
    num = int(''.join(map(str, pc1_tidyHex)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0']"
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are done with your `array` you can use:

```
num = int(''.join(map(str, B)))
```

and you will have your integer. If you want it as string, remove the `int()`

Comment: Hi, I got an error, I updated my post above.

That is the only way that I know how to build an array, this is my first doing python.

Comment: @Codelearner777 this is because you are appending an array to the array. In that case you can change to `num = int(''.join(pc1_tidyHex[0]))`

Comment: And about creating an array, you can directly create the array with the values: `pc1_tidyHex = [tidyHex[56], tidyHex[48], tidyHex[40],..etc]` but then you need to change to `num = int(''.join(pc1_tidyHex))`

Comment: This answer doesn't operate in a bitwise manner. you want to use the base argument of `int`.

Comment: @Codelearner777 Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful =)

Answer (score 4):

convert integer A into binary string from LSB to MSB then manipulate the bit with indexing

```
bin_map = [5,3,2,1,6,0,7,4]
A = 0b11110101
binA = bin(A)[2:][::-1]
B = int(''.join(binA[i] for i in bin_map), 2)
# B will be integer 175 or binary 0b10101111
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your idea.
I think I can use this idea on my next step.
What should I do if I want variable B to be an array?

Comment: To keep B as array,  just replace the last line of my code become `B = [binA[i] for i in bin_map]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string join to turn an array of bits into an integer. You need to do some bit shifting:

```
A = 0b11110101

b_map = [5, 3, 2, 1, 6, 0, 7, 4]  # map of bits from your `A`, high->low order

B = 0  # initialize as 0
for target_position in b_map:  # loop through our positions
    B = (B << 1) | (A >> target_position & 1)  # shift by one, pick the target bit from A

print("B: {} (binary: {})".format(B, bin(B)))
# B: 175 (0b10101111)
```

Not exactly sure if that's what you're attempting to do, tho, your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sure you can, though it's convoluted and inefficient: `int(''.join(str(e) for e in array), 2)` compared to something like `sum(v<<i for i,v in enumerate(array))`